# Как эффективнее хранить данные в базе? В сериализованной строке или в отдельной таблице?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица с объявлениями товаров стиральных малишн.

```
+----+-----------------+----------------+
| id | brand_name      |  model         |
+----+-----------------+----------------+
|  1 | brand1          | model1         |
|  2 | brand2          | model2         |
|  3 | brand3          | model3         |
+----+-----------------+----------------+
```

У каждой стиральной машины есть собственные характеристики: тип загрузки, наличие сушки, вес, цвет и т.д.(порядка 40-50 для каждой из модели).

Я на сайте делаю фильтр. Мне нужно выбрать определенные объявления стиральных машин, которые имеют, например только черный и белый цвет и с наличием сушки.

Вопрос в том, как хранить эти характеристики в базе данных, **чтобы потом было быстрее искать**?

Первая мысль, которая пришла в голову: характеристик очень много для каждого объявления, нужно сериализовать массив в PHP и записать его таблицу с объявлениями. А затем по регулярному выражению искать по этому полю.

Второй вариант, создать вторую таблицу и записать все характеристики туда. При фильтрации основную JOIN-ить с той, где хранятся характеристики и для каждого объявления выбирать исходя из выбранных пользователем харктеристик.

Подскажите, пожалуйста как быть, чтобы выборка из базы была быстрее и эффективнее?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: *нужно сериализовать массив в PHP и записать его таблицу с объявлениями* Вторая часть мысли вполне нормальная - если под сериализацией понимать формат JSON. MySQL вполне умеет с ним работать, в т.ч. и индексировать, если версия не очень уж устаревшая. А вот первая часть подкачала - ну зачем делать где-то, кроме сервера БД, то, что он и сам прекрасно умеет?

Comment: Обычно есть две противоположные задачи - быстрый поиск по заданному параметру и быстрое отображение всех параметров по одному объекту. В первом случае в БД требуется 2-3 таблицы, организующие структуру EAV (в гугле и на этом сайте по этим буквам найдете много интересного). Для решения второй задачи, лучше когда все лежит в одном месте, например в JSON. Для идеального случая я бы разложил все в EAV и при записи туда, автоматом бы формировал и сохранял у товара еще и json вариант. А если бы база была например postgresql, а не mysql, то там был бы возможен индексированный поиск прямо в json

Answer (score 1):

Быстрее всего искать по такой БД если у каждого свойства своя колонка. Например, колонка под цвет, колонка под тип загрузки, под наличие сушки, вес, и так далее. Конечно, такой поиск по сколько-нибудь большим объёмам данных будет быстрым только если у вас есть индексы. Составление индексов - это отдельная большая тема, которую следует раскрывать имея конкретные примеры медленных запросов. Создавать индексы заранее, ещё не имея понимания о том, что же будут искать люди, может не иметь смысла.

Хранить характеристики в отдельной таблицы - не самый худший вариант, но нужно иметь ввиду что вы можете сделать только ограниченное количество `JOIN`ов, к тому же здесь вы обмениваете сложности при добавлении колонок на сложности при составлении SQL запроса. Такой обмен не обязательно имеет смысл. Мы говорим о таблице вида:

```
| row_id | model_id    | property_id | property_value |
|--------|-------------|-------------|----------------|
```

У такого подхода могут быть проблемы при сортировке, либо нужно будет иметь несколько таких таблиц под разные виды данных, либо дублировать данные в пустых колонках.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему вам стоит завести дополнительную таблицу, где в отдельном поле будут храниться все характеристики по которым нужно производить поиск.

Это поле будет хранится в виде текста (набор слов или предложений), построить [полнотекствовый индекс](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) по этому полю.

```
CREATE TABLE search_article (
  id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  article_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES article(id),
  txt TEXT(500),
  FULLTEXT idx (txt)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

теперь можно искать следующим образом:

```
SELECT * 
FROM search_article
WHERE  MATCH ( txt ) AGAINST ('+стиральная +белая +сушильная' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

если данные имеют постоянную заранее определенную структуру и набор характеристик, то конечно хранить в таблицах. обязательно задать индексы. тем более, если характеристик много.

если данные имеют заранее НЕ известную структуру, то можно извращаться. но лучше использовать какие-то встроенные средства движка базы данных типа "работа с XML".

универсальное хранилище - самый трудоемкий вариант для реализации. ключевой момент - как пользователи будут указывать что именно им надо найти и как смогут интерпретировать полученный набор записей.